# Displaying more than 10000 records using JSF2.0 autocomplete component

Tags: jsf-2, richfaces

We are using JSF 2.0 and Richfaces 4.3.7 in our project. 
We are using `rich:autocomplete` component. Per our requirement we need to display around 10000+ records in the autocomplete popup.
We are using client side filter to filter the records, since the no of records is huge (more than 10000) we are unable to scroll it properly.

Comment: Plz share wat u r done

Comment: Then you're misusing the autocomplete. Think about it: would you want to use an application that tries to feed you 10k+ possible options to select from, as an end user? Do the filtering on the server-side and present the client with a manageable set of choices